# Fetching data from Firebase Database in wrong order in nested listener

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from `Firebase Realtime Database` but I am getting the wrong order.

I am fetching all Videos ordered by child 'date' and afterwards looking for the publisher and if currentUser has subscribed.

It seems so that he is listing first of one publisher and then of the next publisher.

How can I get the result below the second code block?

```
val ref = database.getReference("/content/videos").orderByChild("date")
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        p0.children.forEach {
            val video = it.getValue(Video::class.java) ?: return
            println("print1: ${video.video_title}") // Print 1
                    val user = database.getReference("users/${currentUser?.uid}/subscriptions/${video.publisher_uid}")
                    user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                            val sub = p0.getValue(Subscription::class.java) ?: return
                            if (sub.subscribed == true){
                                println("print2: ${video.video_title}") // Print 2
                                adapter.add(VideoItem(video))
                            }
                        }
                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

    }
})
```

What I get from `println()`:

```
I/System.out: print1: Video1 // publisher1
I/System.out: print1: Video2 // publisher2
I/System.out: print1: Video3 // publisher1
----------------------------
I/System.out: print2: Video1 // publisher1
I/System.out: print2: Video3 // publisher1
I/System.out: print2: Video2 // publisher2
```

What I want to get from `println()`:

```
I/System.out: print1: Video1 // publisher1
I/System.out: print1: Video2 // publisher2
I/System.out: print1: Video3 // publisher1
----------------------------
I/System.out: print2: Video1 // publisher1
I/System.out: print2: Video2 // publisher2
I/System.out: print2: Video3 // publisher1
```

Comment: The calls to the `onDataChange` callback should happen in the exact same order as you call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` for those references. The only thing I can imagine that'd change that is if caching is involved, in which case I recommend [using `get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_get) rather than `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

@FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your comment.

This is how the working code looks like now:

```
val ref = database.getReference("/content/videos").orderByChild("date")
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        p0.children.forEach {
            val video = it.getValue(Video::class.java) ?: return

            val user = database.getReference("users/${currentUser?.uid}/subscriptions/${video.publisher_uid}")
            user.get().addOnSuccessListener { p ->
                 val sub = p.getValue(Subscription::class.java) ?: return@addOnSuccessListener
                     if (sub.subscribed == true){
                         println(video.video_title)
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

    }
})
```

Comment: In this case, most likely you should also use `get()` for the first request. Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will also help.